# please help me to store integer value with 0 as perfix in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, integer

I have a column with bigint datatype in SQL Server 2005.

I want to store 0347 in that.. (0 should not be removed) means their must be at least four value like: 0034 , 0007, 0423,4445.

Comment: sir what this "rg sql-server" Tag stands for.. i mean what is its meaning..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL will not store the 0 if you use a bigint.

You could use

```
select right('00000000'+ltrim(Str(<bigIntField>)),4) as DisplayVal
```

Change the '4' to what size you want to zero fill the fields to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store a formatted value like that in an integer field. You'd need to store as a VARCHAR.

Unless you have a very good reason, I'd keep it as you have it in the DB, but just format the number for display in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't store formatted data in an integer type field.

Run `sprintf` or similar over the data when you get it out of the database instead.